# htaccess: 301 redirect removing part of url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, woocommerce

I'm trying to move my shop from Shopify to Woocommerce. I have redirections 301 to do before moving my domain name.
In order not to make the .htaccess file heavy, I would like to use regex to remove part from urls.

**I would like to redirect**

From:

https://"my-shop.com"/**products**/"product-name"

To:

https://"my-shop.com"/"product-name"

**And**

From:

https://"my-shop.com"/**collections**/"product-category-name"

To:

https://"my-shop.com"/"product-category-name"

**So to remove "products" or "collections"**

First problem: I absolutely don't know how to code that...
I tried to understand by looking on the web, found some code, but it's too complicated for me, I did'nt success to adapt it to my problem.
If I'm not wrong, to remove "products" for example, it would look like that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Second problem: If I changed a product name or product category, its url should not follow this rule but redirect to a totally different url.
Can I still use regex for other products and product categories, but add a redirection 301 before so it could work for the product / category I modified?

Comment: Could you please do let me know if my solution helped you?

Comment: Yes of course, sorry I didn't have time to try

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following. Following is looking for `products` OR `collections` keywords from URL.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(products|collections)/(.*)/?$ /$2 [NC,L]
```

---

---

OR use this rule in case you could have any string in place of `products` or `collections`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)/?$ /$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you!
What do you mean exactly by "in case you could have any string in place of products or collections."? That removes any thing before the product name or product category name, even if it's not "products" or "collections"?

I tried on https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ (because I haven't moved my domain name yet), it seems to work. And it's sure it doens't need to have "R=301" in the code?

Finally, what's about my second problem, if I add a simple redirection 301 just before this rule you gave me, would it be working ?

Comment: @Tilter69, honestly I am still learning htaccess(so I will try my best to help here). First thing first rules have worked fine for me for given URLs. For your redirect question I think since we are doing external to external move only we may not need 301 redirection, I would like to request you if you could test it in your test environment once and let me know how it goes. It worked for me for given urls would like to hear from you how it went for you, thank you.

Comment: @Tilter69, if you don't have any other rules in your htaccess then you could have these from starting of file. Please do let me know how it goes?

Comment: I have other rules, I wrote those rules at the top, doesn't work

Comment: @Tilter69, not sure if those are impacting these ones, when I checked only these rules only it worked fine for me.

Comment: Do I have to add these rules after "# BEGIN WordPress <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On" ?

Comment: @Tilter69, yes please in case you are using wordpress, make sure you take a backup of your current rules copy and make a new copy for testing purposes only if these are working or not, thank you.